DateTimepicker is not accepting dates locale
I m working on ASP.net MVC project, I have a form where it has to take from and To date, once the data is saved , while editing the dates are not getting bind, the time format of the system and the format given in the project are different. I want to make it universal irrespective of the date format given in the user system. m using datetimepicker in my project as it is getting affected by the system `date format.
I tried  including the different datetime formats included in my jQuery and also to accept it locale
the date is not getting bind the field appears empty while editing.

/*if ($('.datetimepicker').length > 0) {
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
format: moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'),
icons: {
up: "fa fa-angle-up",
down: "fa fa-angle-down",
next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
previous: 'fa fa-angle-left'
}
});
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.  new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker " })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
*/

Please include code directly in your question, rather than in a comment, and format it properly - https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
